# Spark , Scala: How to remove empty lines either from Rdd or from dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark on scala.And I have some empty rows in Rdd. I need to remove them from the Rdd.

And I tried it as :

```
val valfilteredRow = rddRow.filter(row => row!=null && row.length>0)
```

However it did not work.

The rows in Rdd looks like [ with : valfilteredRow.collect().foreach(println) ]:

```
[,AAGGOO]
[,AAAOOO]
[,GGGGGII]
[]
[,UGGG]
```

Comment: Rdd or Df? The , comes from?

Comment: could you please try something like this, val valfilteredRow = rddRow.filter(row => row.mkString("").trim.isEmpty && row.length>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following sequence :

```
val seq = Seq(
  ",AAGGOO",
  ",AAAOOO",
  ",GGGGGII",
  "",
  ",UGGG"
)
```

**With DF**

```
  val df = seq.toDF("Column_name")

  df.show(false)

+--------------+
|Column_name   |
+--------------+
|,AAGGOO       |
|,AAAOOO       |
|,GGGGGII      |
|              |
|,UGGG         |
+--------------+

  df.filter(row => !(row.mkString("").isEmpty && row.length>0)).show(false)

+--------------+
|Column_name   |
+--------------+
|,AAGGOO       |
|,AAAOOO       |
|,GGGGGII      |
|,UGGG         |
+--------------+
```

**With rdd**

```
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(seq)

  val filteredRdd = rdd.filter(row => !row.isEmpty)

  filteredRdd.foreach(println)

,AAGGOO
,AAAOOO
,GGGGGII
,UGGG
```

Comment: With RDD : `value isEmpty is not a member of Any`. It seems it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If your `RDD` is of type `RDD[String]` then you can do like

```
rdd.filter(_.length>0).collect
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Scala but here is what I did in Pyspark:

Suppose you have an input file like:

```
Banana,23,Male,5,11,2017

Dragon,28,Male,1,11,2017
Dragon,28,Male,1,11,2017
```

2nd line is empty.

```
rdd = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE).mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=','))

>>> rdd.take(10)
[['Banana', '23', 'Male', '5', '11', '2017'], [], ['Dragon', '28', 'Male', '1', '11', '2017'], ['Dragon', '28', 'Male', '1', '11', '2017']]
```

you can see that second element is empty, so we will filter it by calculating the length of element, which should be greater than one.

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE).mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=',')).filter(lambda line: len(line) > 1)
>>> rdd.take(10)
[['Banana', '23', 'Male', '5', '11', '2017'], ['Dragon', '28', 'Male', '1', '11', '2017'], ['Dragon', '28', 'Male', '1', '11', '2017']]
```